# Scale and computer cosine similarity of co-occurrence matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization, trigonometry, symmetric

I have a co-occurrence symmetric matrix (1877 x 1877).
I treat columns as features and compute the cosine distance between them. Before that, I scale the matrix (center to the mean and component wise scale to unit variance).

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
X_scaled = preprocessing.scale(mymatrix)
dist = pairwise_distances(X_scaled,metric="cosine")
```

My questions:

1. Should I scale the co-occurrence data before computing the cosine
   distance/sim? The figure below shows the histograms of the actual matrix. The x-axis represents co-occurrence values in the matrix, and y-axis indicates the number of times they appear in the matrix.   [image]
2. The code above returns distance > 1 and distance < 0. How can I ensure that the cosine distance values between 0 and 1? Should I apply [min max scaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) over the *dist* matrix?